# Limit of the ratio of the square root of a Mersenne number to the product of its prime factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Mersenne numbers with prime exponents are numbers of the form $M_p = 2^p-1$, where $p$ is prime. Suppose that $p$ is such that $M_p$ has exactly two prime factors, $\rho, P$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, can we show 
$$
\dfrac{\sqrt{M_p}}{\rho P} < \epsilon
$$
for $p$ large enough with $\omega(M_p) = 2$. Of course if no such $p$ exists, the result would be vacuously satisfied anyway. Supposing that there are large enough such $p$, can we show, say that the non-square-free part of $M_p$ is small enough to imply the result?

Comment: It isn't even known that there are infinitely many composite Mersenne numbers $M_p$, let alone those with restrictions on the number of primes dividing them.

Comment: Oops yes. I'll try to phrase it another way.

Comment: I think this question comes down to showing that the non-square-free part of $2^n-1$ is small enough

Comment: It is known, for example, that if $\rho^2$ divides $M_p$ then $\rho$ is a Wieferich prime (i.e. $\rho^2|2^{\rho-1}-1$).  And these are scarce to the point of practical non-existence (though they do exist).  So...your limit is a fairly safe bet, though I would be surprised if it could be proven, given the general state of ignorance regarding the subject.

Comment: Should stress:  My skepticism is no reason not to try.  Here, you can even get away with a square factor so long as some other conditions get met.  Might be possible to prove enough.

Comment: Indeed, it works for instance when $M_p = \rho \ell^2$ with $\ell$ prime. Note $M_p = (\rho \ell )^2$ is impossible.